# Is it possible to play audio file when the page is not visible

Tags: javascript, web, audio

Is it possible to start audio file in background mode revisited

It's a GPS based web site. When an user is found within some area of radius r   I want the site to play an audio file. This works fine.
But  when the site is in background mode the file is not playing. I use HTML tag  **audio** for audio files. Is it possible to start audio file in background mode?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "background mode revisited" ?

Comment: Because there was a question with almost the same name/

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. What is "background mode" ?

Comment: It means exactly what I wrote in the title of the question: the page where an audio file should be played is not visible. That is some other application is on the top  or just desktop is visible.